# When and in what order does React update the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm having trouble undestanding the exact moment that React updates the DOM.

**Note:** I'm using `styled-components` in the example below.

**See this example:**

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dirac-j6e54

It shows a transition of the `max-height` property of a container.

[image]

It workws as intended. I just don't know **WHY** it works.

**The code:**

Two lists:

- The `shortList` needs `70px` of height
- The `longList` needs `124px` of height

```
const shortList = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
const longList = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"];
```

I have a `styled-component` container named `ListContainerDIV` that will handle the transition based on `props`. The prop name is `idealHeight`.

```
const ListContainerDIV = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: ${props => props.idealHeight + "px"};
  transition: max-height ease-out .5s;
`;
```

**App Component**

```
function App() {

  // STATE TO KEEP LIST AND REF FOR THE CONTAINER DIV ELEMENT
  const [list, setList] = useState(shortList);
  const containerDiv_Ref = useRef(null);

  // FUNCTION TO TOGGLE BETWEEN LISTS FROM BUTTON CLICK
  function changeList() {
    setList(prevState => {
      if (prevState.length === 3) {
        return longList;
      } else {
        return shortList;
      }
    });
  }

  // CALCULATING THE IDEALHEIGHT DURING THE RENDER
  let idealHeight = null;

  if (list.length === 3) {
    idealHeight = 70;
  } else if (list.length === 6) {
    idealHeight = 124;
  }

  // RETURNING THE LISTCONTAINER WITH THE `idealHeight` PROP
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={changeList}>Change List</button>
      <ListContainerDIV ref={containerDiv_Ref} idealHeight={idealHeight}>
        <ListComponent list={list} />
      </ListContainerDIV>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**List Component**

This is a simple component to render the `<ul>` and the `<li>'s`

```
function ListComponent(props) {
  const listItems = props.list.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>);
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

**QUESTION**

How can this transition be working if I'm setting the `max-height` of the component even before the list is rendered? I mean, `idealHeight` is being set during the App render. I was thinking that `longList` was going to be rendered in a container that already had `max-height = 124` ? And If that happened, we wouldn't be seeing a transition, right?

What is the order of events that React is running in this situation?

Apparently it updates the `<ul>` and the `<li>'s` before it updates the `div` from the `styled-component` container.

An inner component's elements will always be update before the outer component's elements?

---

**UPDATE**

Just found these tweets from Dan Abramov about this subject:

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/981869076166344704

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to calculating the virtual dom, it starts by rendering the parent components, then renders the child components, then their children, and so on. All of this uses the latest values for state and props, so both App and the various child components know that the list is longer. This virtual dom is just an in-memory description of what you'd like the page to look like.

Once the virtual dom has been calculated, react compares the previous virtual dom with the new one, and finds what has changed. In this case, it finds that there's a new style that needs to be added to the div, and some new li's that need to be inserted to the ul. The exact order these are applied are an implementation detail, but they're applied synchronously and the browser cannot paint in between, so it might as well be simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you! Is it for sure that the DOM updates are synchronous and the browser only paints when they're all done?

Comment: Yes, the commit phase of react (my second paragraph) is guaranteed to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to useState, shortList in this case, is the initial state. So when ListContainerDIV is rendered the first time, it's based on the list length being 3, so idealHeight = 70

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I get that. The second render (when the list is update) is what I don't get. If I'm setting the `max-height` even before the `ListComponent` is rendered, how can the transition work?